# Unsure how to implement history.push with react-router v4

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I am playing around with react-router v4 and not sure how to push a user to a new route using history.push, and have resorted to using redirects inside my routes to achieve the same result.

I'd like to use the `logInAndPush()` method in my `LoginPage` component to push a newly logged in user to the `/private_page` route instead of using the redirect logic inside the `/login_page` route. I've tried approaches with `withRouter` and `history` but without success.

(FYI the code below can be pasted into `App.js` of a `create-react-app` app with `react-router-dom` installed)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Link, Redirect, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  state = { loggedIn: false };
  logIn = () => { this.setState({ loggedIn: true }); };
  logOut = () => { this.setState({ loggedIn: false }); };
  render() { return <Home loggedIn={this.state.loggedIn} logIn={this.logIn} logOut={this.logOut} />; }
}

const Home = ({ loggedIn, logIn, logOut }) => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <div style={{ padding: 50 }}>
      <h2>Routing with React-Router</h2>
      <hr /><Navigation loggedIn={loggedIn} logOut={logOut} /><hr />
      <Switch>
        <Route
          path="/private_page"
          render={() => (
            loggedIn === true ? (
              <PrivatePage />
            ) : (
              <Redirect to="/login_page" />
            )
          )}
        />
        <Route path="/public_page" component={PublicPage} />
        <Route
          path="/login_page"
          render={() => (
            loggedIn === false ? (
              <LoginPage logIn={logIn} />
            ) : (
              <Redirect to="/private_page" />
            )
          )}
        />
        <Route exact path="/" render={() => <Redirect to="/public_page" />}/>
      </Switch>
    </div>
  </BrowserRouter>
);

const PrivatePage = () => <h4>This Is The Private Page</h4>;

const PublicPage = () => <h4>This Is The Public Page</h4>;

const LoginPage = ({ logIn }) => {
  const logInAndPush = async () => {
    await logIn();
    // push user to /private_page
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <h4>Click on button to logIn</h4>
      <button onClick={logInAndPush}>logIn</button>
    </div>
  );
};

const Navigation = ({ loggedIn, logOut }) => {
  const logInLink = loggedIn ? (
    <button onClick={logOut}>logOut</button>
  ) : (
    <Link to="/login_page">Login Page</Link>
  );

  return (
    <nav>
      <Link to="/private_page">Private Page</Link><br />
      <Link to="/public_page">Public Page</Link><br />
      {logInLink}
    </nav>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you spread props into the login page you will then have access to react-routers history. You can then use that to push the new route.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Link, Redirect, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  state = { loggedIn: false };
  logIn = () => { this.setState({ loggedIn: true }); };
  logOut = () => { this.setState({ loggedIn: false }); };
  render() { return <Home loggedIn={this.state.loggedIn} logIn={this.logIn} logOut={this.logOut} />; }
}

const Home = ({ loggedIn, logIn, logOut }) => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <div style={{ padding: 50 }}>
      <h2>Routing with React-Router</h2>
      <hr /><Navigation loggedIn={loggedIn} logOut={logOut} /><hr />
      <Switch>
        <Route
          path="/private_page"
          render={() => (
            loggedIn === true ? (
              <PrivatePage />
            ) : (
              <Redirect to="/login_page" />
            )
          )}
        />
        <Route path="/public_page" component={PublicPage} />
        <Route
          path="/login_page"
          render={(props) => (
            loggedIn === false ? (
              <LoginPage logIn={logIn} {...props} />
            ) : (
              <Redirect to="/private_page" />
            )
          )}
        />
        <Route exact path="/" render={() => <Redirect to="/public_page" />}/>
      </Switch>
    </div>
  </BrowserRouter>
);

const PrivatePage = () => <h4>This Is The Private Page</h4>;

const PublicPage = () => <h4>This Is The Public Page</h4>;

const LoginPage = ({ logIn, history }) => {
  const logInAndPush = async () => {
    await logIn();
    history.push('/private_page')
    // push user to /private_page
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <h4>Click on button to logIn</h4>
      <button onClick={logInAndPush}>logIn</button>
    </div>
  );
};

const Navigation = ({ loggedIn, logOut }) => {
  const logInLink = loggedIn ? (
    <button onClick={logOut}>logOut</button>
  ) : (
    <Link to="/login_page">Login Page</Link>
  );

  return (
    <nav>
      <Link to="/private_page">Private Page</Link><br />
      <Link to="/public_page">Public Page</Link><br />
      {logInLink}
    </nav>
  );
};

export default App;
```